# Java: byte[] Array to Excel to BLOB

Tags: java, excel, arrays, export-to-excel, jxl

i have an byte[] array that needs to be converted into an valid excel spreadsheet. After converting the byte array, the excel spreadsheet must be cached into the database  preferably as BLOB.

First I tried to create an WritableWorkbook with:

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(byteArrayOutputStream);
...
workbook.write();
```

This would work fine for me, but i have no idea how to store a workbook as BLOB into the database. Is it even possible? Or is there another way?

Optionally: Instead of the byte[] array I also could use a deserialized object.

Workbook API: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html

Comment: You should at least mention what project you are using in your code sample, best put it in tags too.

Comment: @Marian, what do you mean with 'project' i am using?

Comment: well, where does the Workbook class come from?

Comment: of course, that information is missing. i work with jxl, an excel java api. (added to the tags) http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jdbc method `PreparedStatement#setBlob()` takes an `InputStream` as the data source argument.  Just create a `ByteArrayInputStream` over the buffer of your byteArrayOutputStream and pass that to `setBlob()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in jxl from where we can get outputstream or the byte array from the writableWorkSheet.